# Print Parentheses Pair, get segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, parentheses

I want to print out all valid combination of n-paris of parentheses in C. In the main I give a value 3. That's I want to print out all combination of valid parentheses with 3 left parentheses and 3 right parentheses. However, I got segmentation fault, the gdb prints to `_printValidParentheses(str, leftCount--, rightCount, count++);` line. I am wondering anyone know why I got the fault? Thanks.

```
void printString(char * str) {
    while (*str) {
        printf("%c", *str++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void _printValidParentheses(char str[], int leftCount, int rightCount, int count) {
    if (leftCount < 0 || rightCount < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (leftCount == 0 && rightCount == 0) {
        printString(str);
        return;
    } else {
        if (leftCount > 0) {
            str[count] = '(';
            _printValidParentheses(str, leftCount--, rightCount, count++);
        } 

        if (rightCount > leftCount) {
            str[count] = ')';
            _printValidParentheses(str, leftCount, rightCount--, count++);
        }

    }
}

void printValidParentheses(int n) {
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * n * 2);
    _printValidParentheses(str, n, n, 0);
}

int main() {
    printValidParentheses(3);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You decrement / increment the variables in this line:

```
_printValidParentheses(str, leftCount--, rightCount, count++);
```

only after you call the function, so you get [**StackOverflow**](http://www.stackoverflow.com), because the function is called with the same arguments each time, andit calls itself recursively.

Comment: wow, thanks pointing this out. so i changed to `_printValidParentheses(str, leftCount-1, rightCount, count+1);` and works perfectly. Thanks.